# What's the difference between the operator norm and the sup norm

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

What's the difference between the operator norm and the sup norm over $C[0,1]$. a.k.a $\left\lVert x\right\rVert_\infty$ vs $\left\lVert x\right\rVert_{op}$

Comment: What do you mean by 'operator norm' *in this context*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different norms for entirely different purposes.

The supremum norm over $C[0,1]$ is the norm of this particular Banach space. We have that $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}:C[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ and this norm measures the *size* of a continuous function.

The operator norm is used for bounded linear operators that map the elements of one normed space to another normed space. For example, if $L$ is a bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are two normed spaces, then the operator norm is defined as the smallest $M$ such that $\|Lv\|_Y\le M\|v\|_X$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) for more details). The operator norm measures the *size* of an operator.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: So whats the difference between $\left\lVert f-g\right\rVert_\infty$ and $\left\lVert f-g\right\rVert_{op}$ for $f,g\in C[0,1]$?

Comment: @ElkanaTovey Writing $\|f-g\|_{op}$ does not make sense. The input of $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ is an operator and $f-g$ is a continuous function.

Comment: What if I considered $f-g$ as a bounded operator?

Comment: @ElkanaTovey How would you define it?

Comment: $f,g\in C[0,1]$ such that they are bounded

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, if you want to use the operator norm, you need two normed spaces and an operator that maps the elements of one space to another. Otherwise it does not make sense. A continuous function is not an operator per se.

Comment: Whether you "consider" $f-g$ as an operator doesn't matter. It **is not** an operator, so it does not have an operator norm.

Comment: even if I pick them such that $f(x)-g(x)=(f-g)(x)$ and $f(ax)=af(x)$?

Comment: @ElkanaTovey You have to define an operator if you want to use the operator norm. Try to find some examples of operators.